# How to reset my LG Rumor Reflex if I forgot security pin

Tags: locked-out, hard-reset

How do I hard reset my LG Rumor Reflex? I forgot my security PIN, please give me steps to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Pres Volume down + power button for 10s.
Then it will enter into boot loader.Then select recovery option.
If it is Stock recovery then it will show "Command not found" message then press power button + volume up button once.
Then you will get reset phone option and hit 'yes' to reset phone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open phone's Dialer [ like how we do emergency call]
2. Type the following code: `2945#*#`
3. Confirm the whole operation by pressing Call key.
4. Success!
5. Your phone is unlocked.

Comment: My answer is updated...